# how can i type cast my array object to string in my view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

/*this is my ontroller and array object has to be converted to string type so that i can perform my action

namespace taskmvc.Controllers
{
    public class dogController : Controller
    {

```
    public ActionResult dog()
    {
        string[,] array = new string[7, 14]
        {

            {"D","G","O","O","D","D","O","D","G","O","O","D","D","O"},
            {"O","D","O","O","G","G","G","D","O","D","G","O","G","G"},
            {"O","G","O","G","D","O","O","D","G","O","O","D","D","D"},
            {"D","G","D","O","O","O","G","G","O","O","G","D","G","O"},
            {"O","G","D","G","O","G","D","G","O","G","G","O","G","D"},
            {"D","D","D","G","D","D","O","D","O","O","G","D","O","O"},
            {"O","D","G","O","G","G","D","O","O","G","G","O","O","D"}
        };

        ViewData["f"] = array;



        return View(array);
    }

}
```

}

/* this is my view here you can see that my array is a string

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "dog";
}

<h2>dog</h2>

@{
    string [,] array = ViewData["f"];
    int i, j;
    var n = 7;
    var m = 14;
}


@for (i = 0; i <n;i++)
{
              for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                {
                    if (array[i, j] == "D")
                    {
                        if (j + 1 < m && array[i, j + 1] == "O")//
                        {
                            if(j + 1 < m && array[i,j+1]=="G")
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (i+1<n && j + 1 < m && array[i + 1, j + 1] == "O")
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < n && j + 1 < m && array[i + 1, j + 1] == "G")
                         {

                         }
                    }
                    else if (i - 1 >0 && array[i - 1, j] == "O")//
                    {
                        if (i - 1 > 0 && array[i - 1, j] == "G")
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else if (j-1>0 && array[i, j - 1] == "O")
                    {
                        if (j - 1 > 0 && array[i, j - 1] == "G")
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else if(i + 1< n && array[i +1, j ] == "O")
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < n && array[i + 1, j] == "G")
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else if(i+1<n && j-1>0 && array[i+1,j-1]=="O")
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < n && j - 1 > 0 && array[i + 1, j - 1] == "G")
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else if (i-1>0&&j-1>0&&array[i-1,j-1]=="O")
                    {
                        if (i - 1 > 0 && j - 1 > 0 && array[i - 1, j - 1] == "G")
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else if(i-1>0&&j+1<m&&array[i-1,j+1]=="O")
                    {
                        if (i - 1 > 0 && j + 1 < m && array[i - 1, j + 1] == "G")
                        {

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Your `for` index limits are wrong. They should be 6 and 13. Indices start from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j < 14`, so `max(j) = 13`, `j+1 = 14`, `array[i,j+1]` is illegal.
j+1 is out of range.

Check before:

```
if(j+1 < 14 && array[i,j+1]=="G")
```

...and in many other places.
Also, replace 7 and 14 with variables. For example:

```
var n = 7;
var m = 14;

if(j+1 < m && array[i,j+1]=="G")
```

Comment: thanks its working now but instead of printing value of a i want to print the location how can i get that for D O G when it finds it

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking array[i+1, j+1] , array[i - 1, j],array[i+1,j-1], then you should use the following loop :

```
 for (i = 1; i <6i++)
            {
                for(j=1;j<13;j++)
                {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access array[i,j+1]

for last index j=13, and j+1 will be "14"
So you are accessing array[i,14]
As this memory location not allocated to to your array, You will get index out of range exception.

Try looping from i=0; j=0; and avoid situation like array[i-1,j-1]. (Boundary Conditions)